# Maven Multi Module project fails on Jenkins Pipeline as the agent is not of the same os as being enforced by maven-enforcer-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multi-module

I have a multi module maven project made in Java and utilizing swt. I have a Jenkins instance where I have two slaves. One is windows based and other is linux based. Both have labels on them. In my Jenkinsfile I have specified the agent as 'any'. A few project in my multi module maven project are using maven-enforcer-plugin to enforce the os as windows. When my build starts Jenkins will pick up the linux based slave and my build will fail with the following error(s).

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireOS failed with message:
OS Arch: amd64 Family: unix Name: linux Version: 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 is not allowed by Family=windows
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.3.1:enforce (enforce-execution-environment) on project <xyz-project-using-swt>: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
```

How do I resolve this? Any ideas? If this is a repeated question feel free to close it and point to the previous question.

Comment: Just don't specify the agent as any?

Comment: You need to bind the job for this project to run on a windows node only cause your enforcer rules gives you the hint...

Comment: If I bind the job to an agent or an agent of a type Windows only windows nodes are being utilized for the reactor build and linux nodes remain unused.